# ImportError: libgsl.so.25 when importing python package

Tags: python, package, sage

I've just installed Sage Math as per the conda installation instructions on a linux mint system. When I try to import the Sage package into python using the command:

`from sage.all import *`

I get the following error:

ImportError: libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This worked on my other computer, however can't figure out why it isn't working with this install.

Anyone got any suggestions? I'm guessing I need to somehow point python towards the libgsl.so.25 file.

Comment: I have a good running sage environment... Looking for that library...`[dan@32 /usr/lib]$` `locate libgsl.so.*` giving 
`/usr/lib/libgsl.so.27` and 
`/usr/lib/libgsl.so.27.0.0` as only matches, i got no so-25-match... Which is the output of the above locate line on the other computer? The sage version may be also relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, my guess was that my installation of libgsl was conflicting with the one that sagemath uses, so i deleted my libgsl libraries from /usr/local/lib and reinstall sage, after that it worked.

Comment: Please consider removing this answer.  It seems that you have made a comment.  Please, use the comment instead.